# Jenkins + Xcode Plugin .dSYM not correspond to build

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, testflight

I am using Jenkins to produce and distribute builds for an iOS application and for that I installed the xcode and the TestFlight plugins. The build and archiving succeed but uploading the dSYM to TestFlight fails with the following error:

"Incorrect response code: 400
The .dSYM does not correspond with this build. Are you sure you uploaded the correct one?"

I checked that the .dSYM sent is the one generated by the xcode plugin build and also checked the contents of the dSYM and everything seems fine.

I am using xcode 5 and the last stable versions for Jenkins and the xcode and Testflight plugins.

If anyone has any idea about what can be happening here, I would appreciate the help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure Testflight is up and running, they have been dealing with some issues for the past weeks, you can check this URL:

[Testflight Status](http://status.testflightapp.com/)

Also, double check all the options for the xcode plugin for Jenkins, something may be changing the dSYM file.

Make sure the option *Generate Archive* for the Xcode plugin is not checked, as this option has been added in the latest release of the plugin and it may be the source of the problem:

[Xcode plugin - Jenkins http://goo.gl/mWuPQ0](http://goo.gl/mWuPQ0)

Comment: Thanks Edgar! The problem was the Generate Archive option in the Xcode plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I can verify that it is the "Generate Archive" option being checked that causes the failure.  Looking through my Jenkins logs, when the xcarchive is generated, xcodebuild creates a DSYM for it that overwrites the one for the uploaded build, hence the DSYM does not correspond to the IPA.  Thanks Edgar!

Comment: Yes you are right. The logs showed two dSYM files being generated during the build process in Jenkins. Thanks!